# Excel / Sheets: How do I filter addresses based on a list of zip codes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm planning to mail some postcards to potential business contacts.

I've got a spreadsheet of 2,500+ addresses with columns including `Name`, `Street Address`, `City`, `State`, `zip code`, etc. that cover the entire state of Colorado. But I only want to send the postcards to people near me and I have a list of around 150 zip codes that I'd like to narrow the list to.

I've tried a number of things and haven't been able to get it to work. Ideally, I could output the filtered list of names and addresses to a new spreadsheet tab.

The name, address and other info are in columns `B` through `W`. The list of target zip codes is in column `AM`.

Any advice on how to get this done? I'm not technical and very frustrated. I can't get the Advanced Filter to do the job. The `X` & `VLOOKUP` functions have eluded me.

If you could include an exact formula that only needs a little tweaking, that would be ideal. :-)
Thank you!

Comment: Sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n873n5wGq8KHZf05xViqtfY-e2PFqfH4xfcOc1F2vYE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser. Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1782477/edit) instead of adding information in comments. Also, please include a sample data and expected results either as screen caps (upload to http://imgur.com and line to them) or tables ([how to format tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow), otherwise the question becomes incomprehensible (and thus useless) once the link to the google sheet goes dead

Comment: There are guides for filtering one list by another list. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

#### Basic Syntax

```
=FILTER(range,COUNTIF(lookupValues,zipCodeColumn))
```

#### Sample Formula

```
=FILTER(A:D,COUNTIF(G2:G5,D:D))
```

[image]

#### More Excel Reading

- [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)